# Find the equation of the tangent line to the intersection curve of the surfaces $x=2+\cos(\pi yz)$ and $y=1+\sin(\pi xz)$ at the point $(3,1,2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Find the equation of the tangent line to the intersection curve of the two following surfaces at the point $(3,1,2)$:

$$x=2+\cos(\pi yz)$$
$$y=1+\sin(\pi xz)$$

---

The only way that I know to find the intersection curve is by plugging one of the surfaces into the other one:

$$x=2+\cos(\pi (1+\sin(\pi xz))z)$$

However I really doubt if this is how I should solve the problem.

Comment: You could find the tangent plane to each surface at that point then find their line of intersection.

Comment: There are two answers so far, both correct. Please take your time to study them and ask your questions should you have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We find normal vectors to the tangent planes of both surfaces at $(3, 1, 2)$.

$S1: f(x, y, z) = x - \cos(\pi yz) - 2 = 0$
$S2: g(x, y, z) = y - \sin(\pi xz) - 1 = 0$

$f'(x, y, z) = (1, \pi z \sin (\pi y z), \pi y \sin (\pi y z))$
$g'(x, y, z) = (- \pi z \cos (\pi x z), 1, -\pi x \cos (\pi x z))$

$f'(3, 1, 2) = (1, 0, 0)$
$g'(x, y, z) = (- 2 \pi, 1, - 3 \pi)$

The tangent line to the intersection curve of both surfaces at point $(3, 1, 2)$ should be on tangent planes of both surfaces. In other words, it is the intersection line of both planes.

To find direction vector of the intersection line, we take cross product of both normal vectors and that is $(0, 3 \pi, 1)$.

So the equation of tangent line is $ \ (3, 1, 2) + (0, 3 \pi, 1) t $.

Comment: downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: Too much detail which was not asked for, leaving no real learning opportunity for the student.

Comment: @Paul, You are not supposed to use the voting that way because you have no authority to talk about someone else’s opportunity to learn. You might have hurt the feelings of a person that unlike you it really tried to help by providing a correct answer. We are not here to judge a correct answer to the point of demeaning the person that provided it. Please revisit and understand the code of ethics that you have already adhered to in order to be part of this community.

Comment: @Windsoul the learning opportunity was something of an aside. I don't think it answered the question asked. If the student said "Please give me a detailed answer to this problem" then I would not have downvoted this answer. If I don't have that discretion then that seems to imply that correct answers are simply detailed solutions. An explanation was also requested. I might also note that I did provide a comment to the student to help them.

Comment: @Paul that's alright. thanks for explaining your downvote. I did try to explain what I thought was necessary. At the end of it if OP is still not clear, I expect OP to ask question. On many occasions, I have spent time with them in chat explaining it to them. Also OP said that they only knew to first find the intersection curve of surfaces which did not work here. So I decided to show them completely that would help them going forward for similar questions. Right or wrong, that was my thinking. None of us are right every time. Again thanks for explaining your downvote. It helps. Take care.

Comment: @masaheb yes that is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. The function that describes the geometric field is $$f(x,y,z)=x-cos(\pi yz)$$
2. The gradient of the field is the vector of highest rate of change, with components $$f_x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x};f_y=\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}; f_z=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}; \vec n=(f_x, f_y, f_z)$$
3. The equation of the plane tangent to any surface generated by a constant value of the field is $$(\vec r -\vec r_0)\cdot \vec n=0$$
4. By intersecting the two plane equations of both surfaces I will obtain a line.

And now the work:

1. $f(x,y,z)=x-cos(\pi yz)$
2. $f_x=1; f_y=\pi z sin(\pi yz); f_z=\pi ysin(\pi yz); \vec{n_{f_0}}=(1,0,0)$
3. $(\vec r-\vec r_0)\cdot \vec{n_{f_0}}=0\Rightarrow (x-3)\cdot 1+(y-1)\cdot 0+(z-2)\cdot 0=0$
4. $g(x,y,z)=y-sin(\pi zx)$
5. $g_x=-\pi zcos(\pi zx); g_y=1; g_z=-\pi xcos(\pi zx); \vec{n_{g_0}}=(-2\pi, 1, -3\pi)$
6. $(\vec r -\vec r_0)\cdot \vec{n_{g_0}}=0\Rightarrow (x-3)\cdot (-2\pi)+(y-1)\cdot 1 +(z-2)\cdot (-3\pi)=0$
7. The tangent line is the solution of linear system $$\left \{\begin{array}{rr} x-3=0 \\(x-3)\cdot(-2\pi)+y-1+(z-2)\cdot(-3\pi)=0\end{array}\right .$$
8. The line tangent to the surfaces of equations $x=2+cos(\pi yz)$ and $y=1+sin(\pi zx)$ at point (3,1,2) is $x=3,y=3\pi z+1-6\pi (\therefore )$

Comment: I thank you for your voting and would appreciate any comment on how to improve my answer.

Comment: For me, the student did not ask for a detailed answer but for a method to solve the problem, having indicated an approach they did not think was correct. You would be giving the student more help if you let them work through the details.

Comment: Does it seem that I did not give the student the strategy to solve in the first half of my answer? Didn’t I then let the student to try on his own and if needed, didn’t I follow the work step by step just in case the student needs to check on his own work? Did you even read my answer before voting it down?